# AJAX Get call sending null to Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The below bit of code is supposed to retrieve logged prices for any specific price date/price date ID.  Everything appears to work, except the value passed to the Controller is always null, "undefined", "", or otherwise lacking a value when passed as a string, and doesn't get passed/throws an error in the View when passed as an int.  I've used a template for this issue that works, but I can't see what's going on here.  Disregarding the end calculations that will probably be in another question, can anyone spot the reason the ID value isn't being passed?  Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PriceDate, "Pricing Date")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PriceDate, Model.PricingDates, "--New Pricing--")
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {
    var $priceValue = $("#PriceDate").val(),
        $pID = { iD: $priceValue };
        $("#PriceDate").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val()) {
        //make AJAX call for historical Price data and populate table
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetPrices", "Sales")',
                data: $pID,
                success: function (data) {
                //Fill data
                    $("#Prices").val(data);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            //clear data
            $("#Prices").val('');
        }
        }).change();
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPrices(string iD)
{
    int priceID;
    Int32.TryParse(iD, out priceID);
    //priceID = iD;

    dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
    var selectedPrice = new List<PricesModel>();
    var accountPrices = db.uspGetPrices(priceID);

    //Do stuff

    return Json(selectedPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <label for="PriceDate">Pricing Date</label>
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PriceDate must be a number." data-val-required="The PriceDate field is required." id="PriceDate" name="PriceDate"><option value="">--New Pricing--</option>
    <option value="2">1/4/2016 6:33 PM</option></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the value of the selected option of the dropdown even before the change event (*specifically on the DOM ready event*). So if none of the options were pr-selected as part of the page load (*Ex : a create pag*e), you will be getting `undefined` as the value  for `$priceValue` variable.

You should read the selected option value of the dropdown inside the `change` event code.

```
$(function(){

    $("#PriceDate").change(function () {

       var $pID = { iD: $(this).val() };

       if ($(this).val()) {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetPrices", "Sales")',
            data: $pID,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#Prices").val(data);
            }
         });
      }
      else {
         //clear data
          $("#Prices").val('');
      }
   }).change();

});
```

Also keep in mind that your current code is calling the `change()` method on the drop down after registering the change event code, on `document ready`. that means the change event will be always triggered after the page DOM is loaded. I am not sure this is intentional!

Comment: That did it.  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm researching this, but what would be the repercussions of not triggering after the page DOM is loaded?